# table name includes the schema name of another user

Tags: sql, oracle

I was running a script on the database that grants execute on all tables for the user 'R_USER' to the 'APP_WRITER' user. I received a "table or view does not exist" error.

to debug I put an dbms_output.putline(r.TABLENAME).

I noticed the problem is that there is a table on the R_USER with the name= 'USER_ARCH.LOGS', there is a schema in the database for the USER_ARCH, so there is this ambiguity.

My question is, how do I drop the 'USER_ARH.LOGS' table in the R_USER schema and not the USER_ARCH schema?

As simply using drop table USER_ARH.LOGS will try to drop the wrong table and give me an "insufficient privileges" error.

Comment: So you got a table name with a `.` in it, is that the issue? If yes, then you can address the table by enclosing the entire name in `"` like `"USER_ARH.LOGS"`.

Comment: yes that is a simple way of looking at it.

Comment: After you solve this problem one way or another, you should find out what sick mind thought table names with dots in them are a good idea. You have to prevent this kind of idiocy from ever happening again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a quoted identifier:

```sql
DROP TABLE R_USER."USER_ARCH.LOGS";
```